# Manipulating a List Values in Nested Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list in a nested dictionary in Python as given below.

I want to add new values to the list.

I found some information but I could not be successful.

How can I do that? This is my dictionary.

```
my_dict = {'motorway': {'left': [100, 120, 130]}, 'trunk': {'left': [200, 240, 290]}, 'primary': {'left': [320, 340, 330]}}
```

**For example I want to add 600, 800,345, 980 values like below.**

```
my_dict = {'motorway': {'left': [100, 120, 130, 600, 800]}, 'trunk': {'left': [200, 240, 290, 345, 980]}, 'primary': {'left': [320, 340, 330]}}
```

Comment: my_dict['motorway']['left'].extend([600, 800]) and my_dict['trunk']['left'].extend([345, 980]) Is that what you are seraching for?

Comment: Why not add values to 'primary' key?

Comment: I have some road data from OpenStreetMap and I want to collect same road data in the same category in a list in dictionary @giago.

Comment: I have no idea about 'primary key' @Rahul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for each in my_dict.keys():
if isinstance(my_dict[each], dict):
    for each_1 in my_dict[each].keys():
        my_dict[each][each_1].extend(range(10)) 
else:
    my_dict[each].append(range(10))
```

---

```
to_update_values = ['motorway']
values_to_be_updated_as_list = {'motorway':[777,345345]}

for each in my_dict.keys():
    if isinstance(my_dict[each], dict) and each in to_update_values:
        for each_1 in my_dict[each].keys():
            my_dict[each][each_1].extend(values_to_be_updated_as_list[each])
```

Answer (score 0):

You just add the entries to the lists:

```
my_dict['motorway']['left'] = my_dict['motorway']['left'] + [600, 800]
my_dict['trunk']['left'] = my_dict['trunk']['left'] + [345, 980]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the lists manually:

```
my_dict['motorway']['left'].extend([600, 800])
my_dict['trunk']['left'].extend([345, 980])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:

first get the list inside your dictionary. for example this is a code to update the first list.

```
 ls = my_dict.get('motorway').get('left') # you can use get API or just use calling by key. the difference here is that when you use get it ll return None if the key is not in the dictionary and calling by key will raise an exception

ls.append(600) # or for multiple values adding just use => ls += [600,800,3000]

print(my_dict)
```